# how to compare two storyboards using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

For File comparison we have FileMerge in the xcode.
How do we compare two storyboard with slight difference.

Do we have any tool in xcode or any third party tool available ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the FileMerge too, but it will be opening the storyboard as XML file not visual.

Comment: If there's a third party tool, I'll bet it simply compares two XML files (like SOAP, a Storyboard is simply a "specialized" XML file) and possibly has "intelligent" output with regards to the differences. (HEY - maybe there isn't an app for that yet! Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to compare with xcode. You may use two instances of xcode running side by side to identify the visual differences.

Given that Storyboards are XML based files:

- If working on different branches, make sure xcode version is same for both storyboards and they have the same starting device & orientation. This would avoid many differences to pop up during comparsion.
- Use a standard file comparator (e.g. kaleidoscope, p4merge or filemerge)

In order to resolve the conflicts use:

- Any of the mergeTools: Very happy with using Visual Studio Code recently (2018) to do small manual merges.

Some tips related to storyboards: http://www.xmcgraw.com/10-practical-tips-for-ios-developers-using-storyboards/